# JPA (ebean) partial mysql date

Tags: java, mysql, date, ebean

For lookup and sorting reason, I used mysql DATE type to store complete dates as well as partial date (of the form 2015-00-00 when month and day are unknown). This way I can simply use mysql date functions to search for an interval of type, for example (much faster than doing it at java level).

However, when I retrieve such a date in a JPA (Ebean specifically, but unsure if it is ebean-specific), I get in this case 2014-11_30, even if I try to get this column in a string (without asking JPA to convert it to a Java date (actually, behavior is the same if I convert it or not, with annotation code).

Any idea to just retrieve the date as a string and manage the conversion by myself ?

Comment: Show us your code ;)

Comment: Not sure if this will solve your problem, but have you tried looking at Converters in JPA? http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter/

Comment: Thanks for the pointer... but that ebean thing does not provide implementations for converters... Think I'll go for int YYYYMMDD manual fields.

Comment: That's because EBean does NOT implement the JPA API. It uses its OWN API.

Answer (score 0):

Just used a workaround and implemented dates as integers of the form YYYYMMDD (with 0s for unknown values, actually I'm emulating the incomplete date in SQL).